# The distinction among ke, gue, que, and ce, ze

Tags: pronunciación

As title, I cannot tell the differences.

The most important is I found some spanish speakers write 'k' instead of 'que'.
Why?

Comment: Where have you seen that? The only valid world you mention is "que" – the others simply don't exist. "k" is sometimes used in SMS messaging and such, for the sake of speed.

Comment: In SMS people write *k* to save characters. Otherwise, in a real text, it looks quite uneducated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because it's a twisted and awful way to write it and you **MUST NOT** learn those forms.

As said before, people are often using these forms probably for speed when writing and not for saving space.

I often see in social media comments like *ke te pasa?* which is actually *¿qué te pasa?*
Alas, people are too lazy to write correctly and prefer this twisted way to express themselves.

It's not a matter of difference in meaning, it's a matter on how you correctly write these words. So anytime you see these, stop reading them. That's not the right way to learn Spanish.

Comment: you have not told me the difference among ke que gue, and ce ze.

Comment: @Phil, there is no difference to explain. Except "que" those words simply DO NOT exist.

Comment: Because you set the tag on your question to "pronunciación" and as @Ustanak and I told you "que" is the only valid word on your question, I'd suggest you go to this link and click on the speaker icon to hear the pronunciation. https://translate.google.com/#es/en/que

Comment: For the record, in chat I almost always write "q" isntead of "que". I take to abbreviations, not transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Im a latino who has seen this word evolve in the past years. evolve or should I say  disolve due to abraviations.
I remember when the txt msgs first started we only had a certain amopunt of characters to send a text msg, so in oirder to save character real state we first chopped "Que" into "q"(always a lower case in between sentences and upper case for questions)(and we also chopped out the upside downe question mark at the beggining of our question text msg.
ej. ¿Que hora es? = Q hora es?

you might say text msging naturally americanized some grammar structure for latinos.

Que = q or Q then evolved to "Ke". skipping the "u" because phonetically "Ke" sounds exactly like "Que".
but it didnt last long because "Ke" became "k". very convinient. Time and character realstate saving.